# Is it possible to have a scriptblock evaluated inside a string?

Tags: powershell

I would like for the resulting value in $s to be "now is then for today"

```
PS H:\> $s = "now is $({if (1 -eq 1){'then'}}) for today"
PS H:\> $s
now is if (1 -eq 1){'then'} for today
```

Comment: What's wrong with `$s = "now is $(if (1 -eq 1){'then'}) for today"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's definitely possible, and pretty easy with [subexpressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7#subexpression-operator--)

You were close, just need to remove the outer set of curly braces

```
$s = "now is $(if (1 -eq 1){'then'}) for today"
$s
```

Comment: Many thanks. "Close, but no cigar." I thought the outer curly braces would indicate that it was a scriptblock. I should try not being so smart.

Answer (score 0):

Delay-bind script-block arguments are an implicit feature that:

```
only works with parameters that are designed to take pipeline input,

    of any type except the following, in which case regular parameter binding happens[1]:
        [scriptblock]
        [object] ([psobject], however, does work, and therefore [pscustomobject] too)
        (no type specified), which is effectively the same as [object]

    whether such parameters accept pipeline input by value (ValueFromPipelineBy) or by property name (ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName), is irrelevant.

enables per-input-object transformations via a script block passed instead of a type-appropriate argument; the script block is evaluated for each pipeline object, which is accessible inside the script block as $_, as usual, and the script block's output - which is assumed to be type-appropriate for the parameter - is used as the argument.

    Since such ad-hoc script blocks by definition do not match the type of the parameter you're targeting, you must always use the parameter name explicitly when passing them.

    Delay-bind script blocks unconditionally provide access to the pipeline input objects, even if the parameter would ordinarily not be bound by a given pipeline object, if it is defined as ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName and the object lacks a property by that name.
        This enables techniques such as the following call to Rename-Item, where the pipeline input from Get-Item is - as usual - bound to the -LiteralPath parameter, but passing a script block to -NewName - which would ordinarily only bind to input objects with a .NewName property - enables access to the same pipeline object and thus deriving the destination filename from the input filename:
            Get-Item file | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name + '1' }  # renames 'file' to 'file1'; input binds to both -LiteralPath (implicitly) and the -NewName script block.

    Note: Unlike script blocks passed to ForEach-Object or Where-Object, for example, delay-bind script blocks run in a child variable scope[2], which means that you cannot directly modify the caller's variables, such as incrementing a counter across input objects.
    As a workaround, use a [ref]-typed variable declared in the caller's scope and access its .Value property inside the script block - see this answer for an example.
```